# Binary classification of .xml files via machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to classify .xml files into two categories (10,000 samples, 5000 each). These files mainly contain english text. I am struggling to find features to train an ML model on.

What I have already tried is that I converted the english text of .xml files to .docx and applied NLP based Naive Bayes classifier but it doesn't give good results because different classes may contain the same english text.

In another approach, I performed Ordinal Encoder on the english text and fed it to a dense network but no luck.

I think the NLP approach was a bad one and I should stick to deep neural network. But what features should I use, like filesizes? Also, is there any way to feed a neural network with binary input (like converting the files into binary first) ?

Comment: What are the categories in this case?

Comment: They are called Class A and Class B.

Comment: How do they differ, semantically?

Comment: The files structure is more or less the same but the english content differs most of the time

Comment: How about using doc2vec to represent each xml document as a vector and building a neural network to do the binary classification?

Comment: Isn't doc2vec nlp based? nlp classifier already failed